# How to find the first '0' in a column of numbers using app script [GOOGLE SHEETS]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have range B3:B300 full of numbers. I want to identify the first cell that contains a '0'. I ultimately want to identify the row that contains that cell so the row can be referred to later in the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
function findTheFirstZero() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(3,2,298,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]=='0') {
      return i+3;//return row number;
    }
  }
  return 0;//if no '0' is found
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `if(vA[i][0]==0)` without quoting the `0`?

Comment: It could be,  I didn't write the question and that's what's in  the question.

Comment: That is valid and the reason I thought you would give. The question could be a little more clear.

Comment: It may be exactly what the OP wants?  They'll let us know when they return.  It's an easy change.